# Android Simulate Roaming

Tags: android

I have an application which takes certain action when Phone gets a Roaming event.To test that its perfectly working , can i simulate the SIM Roaming event.Its not practically possible for me to do that in reality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DDMS in Eclipse you can simulate all situations, ... low battery, roaming, no signal .....